# openvpn server for mobile access routing/bridging

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, bridge

I'm running a web server on an IPC and want to get access to the network with VPN, because the customer doesn't want to host his data directly on the internet. This web server runs a webapp, which should be awailable for different (mostly) mobile devices. Therefore I chose OpenVPN for the connection.

Now I'm trying to install and configure the OpenVPN server on my server machine, but don't actually know if I should go for routing or bridging? Is there any difference between Android and iOS devices, that I should consider, if they both use the OpenVPN client?

There will be more than just one device connected to the same network at the same time.
Because I won't know how much and which devices there will be, I want to use a preshared key.

There is a portforwarding setup in my router and the router got a static ip adress.

All I want is, that the user will login on his vpn client(with the static ip/port of the router) and open up the browser, type in the ip adress of the webserver and finally the website/webapp should appear.
Sould I go for routing or bridging? I don't get it, sry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a standard / unmodified Android device you can only use routing - not bridging. This is because Android only supports TUN tunnels, not TAP tunnels.

> Q: Why doesn't the app support tap-style tunnels?
>
> A: The Android VPN API supports only tun-style tunnels at the moment.
>   This is a limitation of the Android platform. If you try to connect a
>   profile that uses a tap-based tunnel, you will get an error that only
>   layer 3 tunnels are currently supported.If you really want to see
>   tap-style tunnels supported in OpenVPN Connect, we would encourage you
>   tocontact the Google Android team and ask that the VpnService API be
>   extended to allow this. Without such changes to the VpnService API, it
>   is not possible for non-root apps such as OpenVPN Connect to support
>   tap-style tunnels.

Source: https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-android-faq.html